RestClient as Singleton
The documentation of RestSharp contains the following section:

RestClient lifecycle
Do not instantiate RestClient for each HTTP call.
RestSharp creates a new instance of HttpClient internally, and you
will get lots of hanging connections, and eventually exhaust the
connection pool.
If you use a dependency-injection container, register your API client
as a singleton.

Could you please confirm the correctness of below (.NET 8) code?
The interface IRestClient implementation RestClient is registered as Singleton (E.g. AddScoped and AddTransient are not allowed).
services.AddSingleton<IRestClient>(options =>
{
    var env = options.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var url = env.GetValue<string>(Constants.MY_URL)!;
    
    var restClientOptions = new RestClientOptions(url)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };
    return new RestClient(restClientOptions);
}

Other service classes are using IRestClient (via DI).

Your code correctly configures a service collection to register IRestClient as a singleton. Typically this means you're in good shape, but there's always a possibility that code you haven't included might affect things. For example, a competing registration of IRestClient executed after this one would take precedent. Or if your consuming classes instantiate their own RestClient rather than injecting an IRestClient, then your DI configuration will have no effect on that.
